# What's the difference from Calendar.DATE and Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH?

Tags: java

Is there any difference when I called:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
```

?

Comment: Why still using Calendar? Answer is in the api doc, they are synonyms. That means no difference.

Comment: If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of `Calendar`, you'll find the following tidbit for [`DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE): *"This is a **synonym** for `DAY_OF_MONTH`"*

Comment: Always read the documentation before posting.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Yes, please consider the new java.time classes. They are much less confusing than the legacy classes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the api doc for [java.util.Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE) (emphasis mine):

> public static final int DAY_OF_MONTH
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the day of the month. **This is a synonym for DATE.** The first day of the month has value 1.

“[Synonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synonym)” means a word with the same meaning.
these two constants mean the same thing and are interchangeable.

Also if you look in the code, you'll notice these constants are defined with the same value:

```
/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DAY_OF_MONTH</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DAY_OF_MONTH
 */
public final static int DATE = 5;

/**
 * Field number for <code>get</code> and <code>set</code> indicating the
 * day of the month. This is a synonym for <code>DATE</code>.
 * The first day of the month has value 1.
 *
 * @see #DATE
 */
public final static int DAY_OF_MONTH = 5;
```